# Rearranging array in simulink

Tags: arrays, simulink

I would like to rearrange an array in simulink. This needs to be done realtime because I am make the simulink model to be loaded into D-space.

My problem is that I am receiving data through a rs232 port with a termination char, but this char are not always on the end. For example if my termination char is x, I would receive for example [3,4,5,x,1,2]. And I would like this to be rearranged to [1,2,3,4,5,x].

Does anybody know how to do this in simulink?

I tried using a matlab code block:

```
function y = fcn(u)

y = zeros(length(u),1);

help1 = zeros(length(u),1);
help2 = zeros(length(u),1);

sa = 1;

n = length(u);

for i=1:length(u)

    if sa == 1;
        help2(i) = u(i);
    else
        help1(i) = u(i);
    end

    if u(i) == 255
        if u(i-1) == 256;
            n = i;
            sa = 0;
        end
    end
end

y = [help1(n+1:length(u)); help2(1:n)];
```

This works fine normally, but when I try to build into onto my d-space, it cannot handle the term `n+1:length(u)` because it is not known statically. Also it cannot resolve the matlab function `circshift`, so I cannot use that...

Any ideas?

Comment: do you always know before how to rearrange it? Then you can jsut `demux` your array and `mux` it in the correct order. If not, than you can write a user defined function, which analyses your array and reorder it.

Comment: Have you tried using a MATLAB Function block to do the rearranging?

Comment: I have tried that, but when I try to build the model, it complains about stuff not being statically known or not being able to eliminate matlab functions (like circshift).

Comment: Any suggestions on what this function block would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your loops to avoid dynamic indexing. For example:

```
function y = fcn(u)

y = zeros(length(u),1);
n = length(u);

for i=1:length(u)
    if u(i) == 255
        if u(i-1) == 256;
            n = i;
        end
    end
end

for i=n+1:length(u)
    y(i-n) = u(i);
end

for i=1:n
    y(length(u)-n+i) = u(i);
end
```